# Dynamic Row Only Added on First Click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have an application that seems to work pretty well except for one small glitch that I can't seem to figure out.  I am hoping for some help here.

I have a table that I can dynamically add rows to.  There are two ways to add rows, some with a checkbox that loads pre-determined data, or an image, which adds a blank row to the table.

The checkbox works great, but the image link only works the first time, and not the next.

This is the image line:

```
<img src="img/plus.png" width="25" height="25" id="btnAddRow" title="Add New Row" class="idfirst alternativeRow" />
```

alternativeRow is generated from code from here: http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/table.addrow.php (example #10, but much more complex) and that line is this:

```
$(".alternativeRow").btnAddRow({oddRowCSS:"oddRow",evenRowCSS:"evenRow"});
```

The "idfirst" block of jquery code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".idfirst").click(function(){
    result = 0;
    id = 0;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'getItemID.php?q=<?php echo $q; ?>',
        success: function(result) {
            id = result;
            if(result.isOk == false)
                alert(result.message);
        },
        async: false
    });          
    window.location.href='page.php?q=<?php echo $q; ?>&id=<?php echo $id; ?>';     
});
});
```

I do the reload because I want the new number created in getItemID.php to dynamically load.  This is important because it also is added to a link that is created within the new row.  The code in getItemID is as follows:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$description = $_GET['description'];
$rate = $_GET['rate'];
$hours = $_GET['hours'];

$query = "INSERT INTO items (q, description, hours, rate) VALUES ('".$q."','".$description."','".$hours."','".$rate."')";

$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$nextId = mysql_insert_id();

echo $nextId;
```

So my problem is that when I click the image link the first time, everything works great, and I get my blank row, the links in the dynamic row work properly, life is good.

But the moment I press it a second time, the page will reload, but I don't get my new row.  It will only return the existing rows before the refresh.

I am wondering if anyone can see something I'm doing wrong and offer any advice. (Yes, I understand that some of this is maybe not the ideal way to make it work, but for the most part it is working the way I need it to...and I've spent tons of hours to make all these moving parts get along).

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Is that image line created for each row? If so it can't have an ID, jQuery will only respond to the first item on the page if there are items with duplicate ID's

Comment: I see you're jquery selector is the image class $(".alternativeRow"). Are you sure that it's not changing in the process?

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments.  That image line only occurs once in a row below the table.  The content rows are loaded through a loop, and after that, this line is added.  @Kalid: The jQuery alternativeRow only occurs once, and it's not in any of the loops...  Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to figure it out.

I was testing this out in IE, which the users will all be using.  Same issue in Firefox, which I use.

I came across this article http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-json-ajax-caching/ and once I tried it in Chrome, it turned out to be a browser issue.  So I implemented the following solutions:

I added

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache:false });
```

to the top of my script, and for good measure, added

```
cache: false,
```

to my ajax call.

Now it works great everywhere.